# How do you know if a dll is "bin deployable"?

Tags: asp.net

I am using [SmartIrc4bet](https://www.meebey.net/projects/smartirc4net/) to allow visitors of my site to chat on irc. My site is in 4.0 but the dll is in 2.0. Everything works fine locally (connects, join a room, send and receive messages using the webpage as a portal).

When I upload it to my host it breaks. The rest of the ASP.NET app works fine and there are no JavaScript errors in the web inspector. So it's kind of a silent crash.

I emailed my host and they said to make sure the dll was bin deployable but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Maybe this article is your answer: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: i dont think so because its not a MVC app